# Form 8829 and Multiple Businesses

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business, accounting

I work from home and had income from 3 sources

1) as an employee of an S corp (which I'm a small part owner of) main source of income
2) Consulting done under my name individually, separate from my day job
3) A single member LLC was created for the apple app store

All 3 are coding related in a dedicated home office room sharing the same equipment.  Do I need to file a 8829 for each income or combine them all on one?

Comment: Employees and partners are not supposed to use Form 8829. You might want to ask an accountant if this applies to employees and owners of S Corporations or not.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually had the same problem several years running, and it's solved by filing my corporate taxes, then taking those schedules, and applying them to my 1040, along with a [Schedule C](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sc.pdf)  You'll want to work with an accountant on this, but basically you're going to take the total set of business expenses as 1 chunk, then write them off your income (as one chunk).  I always recommend an accountant for this, but that's the general idea that I've used, and for the last 10 years, it's worked great.